# Data Analysis with Python and Pandas Tutorial, part 7 from sentdex

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, quandl

Video Link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkIW0YLoQEE&index=7&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDc-3szzjeP6N6b0aDrrKyL-

I'm having a difficult time with keeping the labels of the "State Name" columns in my code that has a "for loop" running through "indexed" data that the gentleman demonstrates through the video. I've noticed the tutorial is close to two years old, but I'm not entirely sure if some sort of patch or update is preventing my code from fully operating

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import pickle

api_key = open('C:\\Users\\TheSalt\\Documents\\{apicode}.txt','r').read()
fiddy_states=pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
#print (fiddy_states) 
main_df = pd.DataFrame() 
for abbv in fiddy_states[0][0][1:]:
   query ="FMAC/HPI_" + str(abbv)
   df = quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)
   if main_df.empty:
       main_df = df
   else:
       main_df = main_df.join(df, lsuffix= '.')

print (main_df)
```

Output:
[A Snip It of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy5pr.jpg)

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please fix your grammar? I would love to help, but find it nearly impossible because you expressed your problems in a poor manner.

Comment: @user3576467: it seems understandable in English terms to me. What did you not understand? As it goes, this post is fairly high in readability terms, compared to some on the site...

Comment: It's only this sentence: `I'm having a difficult time with keeping the "State Name" columns in my code has the "for loop" is running through an "indexed" data that gentlemen demonstrate through the video.` Can you please help clarify it?

Comment: I apologize. Is it easier to read now?

Comment: If it needs to be better explained, I'm not understanding why the output is showing me generic "Value's" as the column labels when it is iterating through data that already has the abbreviations of the states as the labels. The labels seem to disappear.